# struggling to install node-sass in react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm, sass, node-sass, locomotive-scroll

It all began after installing `locomotive-scroll`. I have been trying to install node-sass in my react app. I tried `npm install node-sass` but I got an error `ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT` I can't even run `npm start` command, it gives these errors

```
./node_modules/locomotive-scroll/src/locomotive-scroll.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./node_modules/locomotive-scroll/src/locomotive-scroll.scss)
To import Sass files, you first need to install node-sass.
Run `npm install node-sass` or `yarn add node-sass` inside your workspace.
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Noname\Desktop\react js\vertical-portfolio\react-app\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\getDefaultSassImplementation.js
- C:\Users\Noname\Desktop\react js\vertical-portfolio\react-app\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\getSassImplementation.js
- C:\Users\Noname\Desktop\react js\vertical-portfolio\react-app\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js
- C:\Users\Noname\Desktop\react js\vertical-portfolio\react-app\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\cjs.js
- C:\Users\Noname\Desktop\react js\vertical-portfolio\react-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
- C:\Users\Noname\Desktop\react js\vertical-portfolio\react-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
- C:\Users\Noname\Desktop\react js\vertical-portfolio\react-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
- C:\Users\Noname\Desktop\react js\vertical-portfolio\react-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js
- C:\Users\Noname\Desktop\react js\vertical-portfolio\react-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js
- C:\Users\Noname\Desktop\react js\vertical-portfolio\react-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js
- C:\Users\Noname\Desktop\react js\vertical-portfolio\react-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
```

I tried `npm cache clean`, `npm audit fix`, then tried with --force both of them. Deleted `node_modules`, run `npm install`, updated all packages with `ncu -u`. I tried `npm clean cache`, but it didn't work too.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.4.2",
    "emailjs-com": "^3.2.0",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
    "gsap": "^3.8.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-gsap": "^3.2.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-loading": "^2.0.3",
    "react-locomotive-scroll": "^0.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.4",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.1",
    "use-in-view": "^1.0.15",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, `node-sass` [is deprecated](https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated).

I'd like to think replacing `node-sass` with `sass` will solve your issue.
You should replace it by doing:

```
npm rm node-sass
npm i sass
```

If the project still throws errors, or demands/requires you install node-sass during runtime, try creating an alias in `package.json` that points to sass to bypass that error:

`"node-sass": "npm:sass@^1.54.4"`